# How does the CSS in Bootstrap 3 cause the breakpoint xs to start out with vertically stacked divs?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I do not understand why using the xs breakpoint causes divs to be vertical instead of horizontal.  When I look at Bootstrap 3, I have:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-xs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
```

What is making it start out vertical?

Bootstrap 4 doesn't have xs, so I looked at sm.  It is flexbox, but I see no `flex-direction` in those selectors.  How does it know to go vertical?

If I have sm in my bootstrap, when I am at that media query, the divs will go vertical. What in the CSS makes it go vertical? If I go to the bootstrap page and resize the window, when I get to sm, the divs that were horizontal are now vertically stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Also, answered in the other question... media queries: "These grid sizes enable you to control grid behavior on different widths. The [different tiers are controlled by CSS media queries](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries)" .. also the `xs` tier *doesn't* stack vertically.

Comment: I see they are media queries, but my CSS isn't good enough to know why that is making them vertical.  Why aren't they horizontal, only very, very small?  Edit:  In other words, I know the media query is for that size screen.  But the CSS to actually make it vertical in that media call is what I'm asking about.

Comment: But `xs` is horizontal, not vertical. The `xs` prevents it from being full width (unless it's col-xs-12).

Comment: @ZimSystem If I have sm in my bootstrap, when I am at that media query, the divs will go vertical.  What in the CSS makes it go vertical?  If I go to the bootstrap page and resize the window, when I get to sm, the divs that were horizontal are now vertically stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Nothing is making it go vertical. In CSS [divs start out vertical](https://www.codeply.com/go/PHhETXD39B). Bootstrap is making them horizontal using float:left and defined width.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used bootstrap in a while but the basic principle would be that a media query handles this. The code that specifically does this could be something like this...

```
/******** The maximum size the XS columns will stay vertical *****/
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   .col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5,
   .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10
   .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
         width:100%;
   }
}
```

As long as the viewport is less than 800px all the 'xs' columns will be 100% width. Anything over that and their default styles as presented in your original question would take over and they would appear horizontal again instead of vertical.

**Update**

Now I'm just curious myself so don't mind taking a look at it. So this is from the BS4 CSS...

```
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col,
.col-auto, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm,
.col-sm-auto, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md,
.col-md-auto, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg,
.col-lg-auto, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl,
.col-xl-auto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
 }
```

So that's the default size for every column. Everyone of them is set to 100% which is why they stack when a media query isn't in effect.

Now for the first set of columns they used this media query

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
     .col-sm {
       -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
        flex-basis: 0;
        -ms-flex-positive: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
       max-width: 100%;
     }
  /*** followed by all the other -sm column sizes ***/
 }
```

If they do this for every column size as the viewport increases it would explain why on the small size they appear to be 100% and vertically stacked despite there being no apparent query to do so. It's all the original css rules that did it.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks.  But if that is the case, then why do they have all the individual ones at different percentages?  Is that because the smaller implies the larger?

Comment: So the basics of the bootstrap grid is that any number of columns that equal to 12 will display on one line. For example col-xs-4 and col-xs-8 would be one line. But col-xs-4 and col-xs-9 would break onto two lines. The percentages are there to ensure that regardless of the viewport size that the rules of having 12 columns per row will work. So for instance a col-*-9 is 75% of 12 which is why it has that as it's width percentage.

Comment: I see the 12 grid system, but that does not tell me what makes a set of divs vertical.  Your media call makes sense.  The Bootstrap one does not.  If I have xs-6 xs-6, sooner or later those will be vertical if I get a smaller viewport.  But since the 12 grid is always present, why don't they stay on the same line, just very, very small horizontally?  The media query only points me to the CSS.  The CSS in that media query doesn't show me why that happens.

Comment: @johnny I may be missing the point of what you're trying to get at so I apologize if this response misses the mark. Again I don't know exactly how bootstrap does it, but as you said that media call I posted works and that's how I handle the smallest set of columns. Bootstrap is mobile first. So those 'xs' sized columns need to be able to go all the way from the tiniest of viewports to a huge desktop size. That's why they have their own widths defined. I'm going to look at the CSS for bootstrap 4 and see if I can't uncover how they do this for you.

Comment: Don't worry about that.  Bootstrap 4 uses flex.  Bootstrap 3 is the other way.  No need to take too much time on it.  I'll keep reading.